# Angular 1.3 adds "null" option to select element

Tags: angularjs

I have a select element defined as such:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedLocale"
    ng-options="l | translate for l in locales"></select>
```

and in my controller I have:

```
$scope.locales = ['en', 'fr', 'it'];
$scope.vm.selectedLocale = $scope.locales[0];
```

With angular 1.2 the result is a select with 3 options. In angular 1.3 there is an extra "null" option with no label. If the translate filter (angular-translate) is removed the null option goes away. Is this the intended behaviour? Is there a workaround that allows me to stick to translations in the view?

Comment: works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/L5qOI8YzG5RTlp8ZWgEP?p=preview

Comment: You will not see the null/empty option if you set vm.selectedLocale to first item in the list(locales) , angularJS adds an empty option when selected value is not set.

Comment: @New Dev thanks, that helped. I am using angular-translate's static files loader and replacing that config with your example works fine. I know better where to look now.

Comment: @Sunil I do set the value.